# Rails tag helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, meta-tags, helper

I want to do 
 `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL='my_url" />`
with [rails tag helper](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TagHelper.html#method-i-tag)

i'm doing like this

```
tag(:meta, 'http-equiv' => (:refresh),:content=>("0;URL=#{my_url}"))
```

but i getting

```
"<meta content=\"0;URL=my_url" http-equiv=\"refresh\" />"
```

where is my mistake?

Comment: I don't get it, what's wrong with what you get? It is the same tag but content and http-equiv are switched. The forward slashed is necessary for ruby to escape special characters but they don't show up in the html page. Is it the order that you don't like or is it the '\' ?

Comment: i dont like  the order or its ok and should work as expected?

Comment: Order of html attributes within a tag don't matter. It should work as expected.